# Get partitioned indices of sorted 2D list

Tags: python

I have "2D" list and I want to make partitions/groups of the list indices based on the first value of the nested list, and then return the sorted index of the partitions/groups based on the second value in the nested list. For example

```
test = [[1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 1], [1, 10]]
sorted_partitions(test)
>>> [[1, 0, 2, 5], [4, 3]]
# because the groupings are [(1, [1, 1]), (0, [1, 2]), (2, [1, 5]), (5, [1, 10]), (4, [2, 1]), (3, [2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coming up with what I thought would be an improvement to my original attempt, I decided to do some runtime tests. To my surprise, the `bisect` didn't actually improve. So the best implementation is currently:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def my_sorted_partitions(l):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for i, (group, val) in enumerate(l):
        groups[group].append((val, i))

    res = []
    for group, vals_i in sorted(groups.items()):
        res.append([i for val, i in sorted(vals_i)])
    return res
```

It is very similar to [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75236870/6045800), but uses a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of `groupby`. This means there is no need to sort the input list (which is required to use `groupby`). It is now necessary to sort the `groups` dict (by keys) but assuming `num_groups << num_elements` it is efficient. Lastly, we need to sort each `group` (by values) but since they are smaller it might be more efficient.

---

The attempted improvement using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) (which removes the need to sort the values, but apparently the "repeated sorting" costs more):

```
def bisect_sorted_partitions(l):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for i, (group, val) in enumerate(l):
        bisect.insort(groups[group], (val, i))

    res = []
    for group, vals_i in sorted(groups.items()):
        res.append([i for val, i in vals_i])
    return res
```

---

And the timing done in [this REPL](https://onlinegdb.com/ZMLrCrqQaF).

The input is randomly generated, but the results from an example run are:

```
My:     28.024
Bisect: 60.325
Orig:   200.61
```

Where `Orig` is [the answer by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75236870/6045800).

Answer (score 2):

My quick solution is to use itertools and groupby. I'm sure there's some alternate approaches with other libraries, or even without libraries.

```
# masochist one-liner
sorted_partitions = lambda z: return [[val[0] for val in l] for l in [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(enumerate(z), key=lambda x:x[1]), key=lambda x: x[1][0])]]  # not PEP compliant

# cleaner version
def sorted_partitions(x):
    sorted_inds = sorted(enumerate(x), key=lambda x:x[1])
    grouped_tuples = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_inds, key=lambda x: x[1][0])]
    partioned_inds = [[val[0] for val in l] for l in grouped_tuples]
    return partioned_inds
```

Comment: Seems like what I would do... Do you have a (specific) problem with it?

Comment: Seems a tad bit forced to me, but I figured I'd put in my answer and also see if anyone has a different approach. For example, I know pandas could do it to, but it would be major overkill.